# Hive query with except conditions

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to build a hive query that does only the below features or a combination of these features. For example, the features include

name = "summary"

name = "details"

name1 = "vehicle stats"

Basically, the query should exclude all the other features in name and name1.

I am quite new to hive. In sql, i know this can be done using except keyword. Just wondering whether there is some functions that can achieve the same.

Thanks very much !!

Comment: can you post some sample data and the expected output as formatted text? it is unclear what you need.

Comment: Something like this: create query with `where 1=2 ` and concatenate your conditions with it using  ` OR `.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive query with certain specific exclude conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286001/hive-query-with-certain-specific-exclude-conditions)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, I approach this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select ?
from t
group by ?
having sum(case when name = 'summary' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when name = 'details' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when name1 = 'vehicle_stats' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

The `?` is for the column that you want the summary of.